# Invoking Mule flows from HTML frontend

Tags: mule

I am new to Mule and my requirement is to run a mule flow on demand .
Wondering whats the best way to configure this in mule. Is there  a way I can build a JSP frontend UI which can then invoke  a mule flow directly .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expose your Mule flow with a HTTP inbound endpoint.

From the HTML make a call to the HTTP url which will invoke your mule flow.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is absolutely a way to invoke Mule flow from JSP front-end (of course you can use any front-end technology you want). All you need to do is to configure a flow with **HTTP Listener** with appropriate method, including GET, POST, PUT, DELETE and an URI. Now from your JSP page invoke this flow using the URI and appropriate method. For more information on HTTP Listener please go through this [link](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/HTTP+Listener+Connector)